# How to attach/upload more images in laravel user mysql database row where there are uploaded images from the past

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, forms, image

Please help me, in Laravel, I have a database, where I have users and patients. In the patients table, I have an "image" row, I upload the multiple images there, their names are imploded by " | " and the directory is /images-patients. It all works fine, but I have a problem when I want the user to attach more images to the current patient, making them more. In PatientController in the update function, I use the same code with the form, for attaching more images and when I want to attach the images to the patient, it removes the old ones and replaces them with the newly uploaded ones. How can I attach more images, by just adding more images in the array, being imploded by " | ", without removing the previously uploaded ones to the patient, when the form is submitted? Here is my code:

patient.blade.php

```
   <div class="card-header">Attach image to a patient {{ $patient -> name }} <span class="float-right" id="close-edit-details-modal" style="cursor:pointer;"><b>X</b></span>
    </div>
  <div class="card-body">
        {{-- Forms --}}
    <form action="{{ route('admin.patients.update') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      @csrf
  @method("PUT")
        <input type="text" name="id" value="{{ $patient -> id }}" hidden>

        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="image">Image</label>
            <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="image[]" />
        </div>


                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn" value="Attach the image">

        </form>
```

PatientController.php

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $request -> validate([
            'image' => 'required',


       ]);

       $destinationPath = './images-patients/';
       $images=array();
       if($files=$request->file('image')){
           foreach($files as $file){
               $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
               $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
               $images[]=$filename;
           }
       }
       $allImages = implode(" | ", $images);


       $patient = Patient::find($request -> id);

       $patient -> image = $allImages;

       $patient -> save();

       return redirect('admin/patient/' . $patient->id)-> with('success', 'Successfully attached photos to a patient!');
    }
```

web.php

```
Auth::routes();

Route::middleware('auth', 'isAdmin')->namespace('admin')->group(function(){

    Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@index')->name('admin.users');
    Route::get('/admin/settings', 'SettingsController@index')->name('admin.settings');
    Route::get('/admin/user/{id}', 'UsersController@getUser')->name('admin.user');
    Route::get('/admin/patients', 'PatientController@index')->name('admin.patients');
    Route::get('/admin/patient/{id}', 'PatientController@show')->name('admin.patient');
    Route::get('/admin/blank', 'BlankController@index')->name('admin.blank');

    Route::get('/admin/patients/search', 'PatientController@searchPatients')->name('admin.patients.search');
    Route::get('/admin/patients/usearch', 'PatientController@searchUsers')->name('admin.patients.usearch');

Route::put('/admin/patients/update', 'PatientController@update')->name('admin.patients.update');
    Route::post('/admin/users/store', 'UsersController@store')->name('admin.user.store');
    Route::post('/admin/patients/store', 'PatientController@store')->name('admin.patients.store');
    Route::put('/admin/user/update', 'UsersController@update')-> name('admin.user.update');
});



Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Try replacing `$patient -> image = $allImages;` with `$patient -> image .= " | $allImages";`

Comment: Well, now it actually puts the names of the files, it doesn't remove the old ones, but it only shows the last uploaded picture from the set or etc, plus it changes the name of the file, look at this picture and the name of the pictures that are not shown: https://imgur.com/JReWFiD do you have any idea how to fix it by chance

Comment: What's the code (blade) for the screenshot linked in your comment? Can you post the code here?

Comment: Hello, your code works, it works perfectly, I replaced $patient -> image = $allImages; with 
$patient -> image .= " | $allImages"; and it is all good now, exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great. So will post the solution as answer which you can mark as accepted/upvote for the benefit of subsequent visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One little change is required in the `PatientController` to get the results you desire.

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $request -> validate([
        'image' => 'required',
    ]);

    $destinationPath = './images-patients/';
    $images=array();
    if($files=$request->file('image')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            $images[]=$filename;
        }
    }

    $allImages = implode(" | ", $images);


    $patient = Patient::find($request -> id);

    //Append the names of newly uploaded files to the existing value
    $patient->image .= " | $allImages";

    $patient->save();

    return redirect('admin/patient/' . $patient->id)-> with('success', 'Successfully attached photos to a patient!');
}
```